# Release Version of CentOS ISO

Tags: centos

I have a CentOS.iso, how can I get its `$releasever`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the root directory of any RHEL / CentOS ISO, you will find two hidden files: `.discinfo` and `.treeinfo`.

The `.discinfo` file will look like this:

```
1504618416.850667
7.4
x86_64
```

The second line indicates this example `.discinfo` file was from CentOS version 7.4.

The `.treeinfo` file will look like this:

```
[general]
name = CentOS-7
family = CentOS
timestamp = 1504618609.47
variant = 
version = 7
packagedir = 
arch = x86_64

[stage2]
mainimage = LiveOS/squashfs.img

[images-x86_64]
kernel = images/pxeboot/vmlinuz
initrd = images/pxeboot/initrd.img
boot.iso = images/boot.iso

[images-xen]
kernel = images/pxeboot/vmlinuz
initrd = images/pxeboot/initrd.img
```

So, if you need just the major release number:

```
# mount -o loop,ro CentOS.iso /mnt
# grep ^version /mnt/.treeinfo | cut -d " " -f 3
7
# umount /mnt
```

If you also need the minor release number ("patch level"):

```
# mount -o loop,ro CentOS.iso /mnt
# head -2 /mnt/.discinfo | tail -1
7.4
# umount /mnt
```

Comment: How to into the CentOS ISO?

Comment: The command `mount -o loop,ro CentOS.iso /mnt` means: "make the contents of the CentOS.iso accessible at /mnt". Your desktop environment may have other tools that allow you to access the contents of the ISO file.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly moderately cheating, but: the CentOS project publishes  [checksums of their official ISOs](http://mirror.softaculous.com/centos/6.10/isos/x86_64/sha1sum.txt) (example link for CentOS 6.10). Run sha1sum on your iso and go compare, the checksum does not depend on the filename. You can also look at the approximate size of the ISOs (but bear in mind some software displays 2^20 bytes as MB, some 10^6 bytes, so better only rule out when the size difference is at least 10%).